# Google Analytics Data API V1 response discrepancy

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am extracting data through the Data API V1 of Google Analytics and I am trying to retrieve data for a specific date range (eg one day) of several dimensions (segmented 7 per request) at the time of extracting it the value of row count is not the same, even keeping dimensions like date or firstSessionDate so that it returns the same number of elements. What might be going on there or how Google Analytics shows your data? I have compared with the exported BigQuery records but there is no match either, BigQuer shows more data than through the API.

I would like to get the same records for the same dimensions to concatenate the API responses.

I am using the python client API.